# Path to the images folder is not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to display an image in one of my view. I have set the path to the image as followed:

```
imSettings.ImageUrl = "~/Content/images/AquaHeader.png";
```

But in the browser I get a "ressource not found"-error. Which is because there is no images-folder inside the content folder when running the application. So why is this folder not available? What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to mark the file as Content.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Can you tell me how I can mark the file as content?

Comment: Right click on the image in Solution Explorer. Click Properties and set its build action as Content.

Comment: Unfortunatly the property is already set to Content

Comment: Change the 'Copy to output directory' to 'Copy always'